# New Server 2012 R2 Essentials generating Audit Failure Event 4625 Null SID Logon Attempts

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, audit, windows-server-essentials

I am researching a failed login issue that is triggering our monitoring software.

Researching the issue, the only other information I could find that was exactly what I was seeing, was on here: [Event 4625 Audit Failure NULL SID failed network logons](https://serverfault.com/questions/686393/event-4625-audit-failure-null-sid-failed-network-logons?newreg=7439372532c747b0a738bb165352ff57)

Trying to track this down, I used Process Monitor and set 2 filters:
Process IS lsass.exe 
Result IS NOT SUCCESS.

I then matched the results with the failed Audit attempts and it seems to correspond to these two lines in process monitor as they showed each time at the exact time of the Audit Failure:

```
1:05:47.4932903 PM  lsass.exe   896 RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root\ProtectedRoots NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read


1:05:47.4941867 PM  lsass.exe   896 RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ForceAutoLockOnLogon NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
```

I am not sure if I am looking at the right place to track this down, or what to do now.  Any Suggestions?

I am new to serverfault so I couldn't comment or answer on the question at the link above, but would be curious if he/she saw the same results with process monitor.

Here is an event viewer event:

```
An account failed to log on.

    Subject:
        Security ID:        SYSTEM
        Account Name:       %domainControllerHostname%$
        Account Domain:     %NetBIOSDomainName%
        Logon ID:       0x3E7

    Logon Type:         3

    Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       
    Account Domain:     

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x380
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\lsass.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   %domainControllerHostname%
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Schannel
    Authentication Package: Kerberos
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

Comment: I know you posted on my post but just to link it back the other way, I've documented a bodge-fix on my post at http://serverfault.com/questions/686393/event-4625-audit-failure-null-sid-failed-network-logons/735117